# RingCentral giving me error of "[OutboundFaxes]" at the time of sending FAX

Tags: api, fax, ringcentral

I am trying to send FAX using POSTMAN using following URL `"https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/****88004/fax"` 
and I'm getting:

```
{
    "errorCode": "CMN-408",
    "message": "In order to call this API endpoint, user needs to have [OutboundFaxes] permission for requested resource.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorCode": "CMN-408",
            "message": "In order to call this API endpoint, user needs to have [OutboundFaxes] permission for requested resource.",
            "permissionName": "OutboundFaxes"
        }
    ],
    "permissionName": "OutboundFaxes"
}
```

Comment: What type of extension is this and what account type do you have, e.g. Office Premium? If you call `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~` what is returned in the type property? When using a `"type": "User"` extension, even the most limited role I can create has the `OutboundFaxes` permission as listed in the `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/authz-profile` endpoint. In the Online Account Portal (service.ringcentral.com) this corresponds to `General: Overview, Messages, Contacts, Standard User Tools` and `Policies: Internal Calls`.

Comment: This error indicates your account doesn't fax capabilities. You can see this by calling the `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/service-info` API endpoint and looking for `"featureName": "Faxes"`. Please create (and monitor) a support ticket following the links at the bottom of this page: https://developer.ringcentral.com/support.html . The team will need your account id / phone number to investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a problem in Bearer Token at the time of making Send Fax request.

Because I was using primary account details for generating Token and at the time of sending FAX I was using extensionid of extension 102 and Bearer Token was generated with Main account extension 101. That is why it was throwing  [OutboundFaxes] permission error.

To send FAX with ExtensionId of extension 102 , then generate the token using subaccount 102 details instead of main account.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully reproduced the issue.

### [test case](https://github.com/tylerlong/ringcentral-js-concise/blob/master/test/fax_wrong_token.spec.js)

The root cause is just what @Jack said: authorize with extension 101 then try to send the fax with extension 102.

The error message is

```
{ errorCode: 'CMN-408',
      message: 'In order to call this API endpoint, user needs to have [OutboundFaxes] permission for requested resource.',
      errors:
       [ { errorCode: 'CMN-408',
           message: 'In order to call this API endpoint, user needs to have [OutboundFaxes] permission for requested resource.',
           permissionName: 'OutboundFaxes' } ],
      permissionName: 'OutboundFaxes' }
```

I think the error message needs to be improved. It's very hard to figure out the root cause by reading it. I have reported this issue to RingCentral engineering team.